# Apache Ant cannot find tools.jar on Solaris 11

Tags: java, ant, solaris

I'm trying to install apache ant on Solaris 11.

I set ANT_HOME but I keep getting this error:

`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/lib/tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed`

How do I resolve this?

Comment: what have you done to install apache ant?

Comment: I downloaded the tar and extracted it. then i added ANT_HOME to the path...

Comment: I also tried installing the latest jdk until I realised there was already an older version

Comment: which command you have used to execute the ant build script?

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: i've tried but i don't actually know what to set it to... everything I've tried has failed thus far

Comment: does build.xml exist in which dir you used ant command?

Comment: it doesn't but having tried this exact method on a linux machine i can't see why it's a problem now...

Comment: i used the ant command in the ant dir and in the cassandra dir (the whole objective ultimately is to install cassandra)

Comment: my understanding is that build.xml should exist in one of the dirs in the path?

Comment: no i think i'm wrong actually.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you either do not have a Java JDK installed or your JAVA_HOME is not pointing to the right place:

Assuming you have the public Oracle Solaris repository configured:

```
mack@solar:~# sudo pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
```

To install ant and Java JDK 8 on Solaris (tested on Solaris 11.3):

```
sudo pkg install ant jdk-8
```

Point JAVA_HOME to the JDK:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0
```

Then you can test your ant installation:

```
mack@solar:~# ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

At least you now have ant configured correctly.